# Adjusting resources for variable workflow

Tags: pbs, torque

I have a file that needs to run through filter programs A, B, C, and D.  A takes 2 hours, B, C, and D vary between 10 and 30 minutes each.

A does most of the work and takes most of the time so it was optimized to use multiple processors.

B, C, and D are single processor.

All of the programs are run sequentially in one PBS script.

If I change the pbs resource requirements after A runs, will it be reinterpreted or does qsub only evaluate that once?

Alternately, if I split this into two pbs scripts, how can I have one start the other on completion?

Comment: Certainly do split into tow scripts, and look up "Job Dependencies" in the manual. Please specify which version of PBS you are using, since dependency syntax may vary between versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Dmitri Chubarov, [Job dependencies](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/help.htm#topics/commands/qsub.htm?Highlight=%22job%20dependencies%22) are the solution to the problem.

Followon processes depend on the job id of the parent.
Jobid is dynamically generated by qsub.
I will put each stage in its own pbs script and have a wrapper bash script call each qsub and pass the jobids around.